# How to get the latencies

Tags: php, android

I have a problem and it drive me crazy. In my app I need to get the value of the local stamp, the latency of a request to server, the server stamp and the latency of the response to the app.

The only values I can get are the local stamp, the server stamp and the time of a complete cycle (request+response). So how to get the request latency, and the response latency.

Comment: Are you doing the request with php?

Comment: No, just the response

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the requests with php you can use something along these lines:

```
<?php
    // start a timer
    $start_time = microtime(true);
    // do some network stuff
    // example is read google.com
    $buffer = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
    // echo the current time minus the start time
    echo number_format(microtime(true) - $start_time, 5) . ' seconds';
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but your microtime() and number_format() are gonna really help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
long sendtime,latncyTime;   
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your-url.com");

            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                    "ARUN"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                    "****"));
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

sendtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
latncyTime=System..currentTimeMillis()-sendtime;



                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: Then you will be getting the latency

Comment: For me the latency is the time a request will take to reach the destination. Am I wrong ?

Comment: My idea is to divide the result by 2. What do you think ?